# How to put an h4 and h1 in the middle of a background image?

Tags: html, css

I have this situation.
HTML:

https://codepen.io/JT_Cerqueira/full/YxOLxg/

The thing is that on the headwraper div, there is a background image and I tried everything to put my h1 and h4 sentences in the middle of the background image but I just don't know how to do it. And of course ran out of ideas.

Could anyone help?

```html
<div id="headwraper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <h4>HELLO WORLD, I'M</h4>
        <h1>JT CERQUEIRA</h1>
        <h4>FRONT END WEB DEVELOPER AIMED AT FULL STACK</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the style.

Comment: Sorry guys I am kind of a newbie here. I have just accepted all the answers. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

Just change the following,
`padding-top:50px;` 
`min-height:770px;`. That will do.

Appreciate if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below css it will make h1,h4 and p tag vertically and horizontally center, I have added class mybox

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 mybox">
        <h4>HELLO WORLD, I'M</h4>
        <h1>JT CERQUEIRA</h1>
        <h4>FRONT END WEB DEVELOPER AIMED AT FULL STACK</h4>
      </div>
.mybox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px !important;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It helped me a lot  again Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `padding-top: 750px;` is pushing your contents down. I tried removing it and added this to your #headwrapper.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
```

Comment: You nailed it. Exactly where I want it. Thanks again.